# Is there a regex to replace leading zeroes (except the last one) and colons in nn:nn:nn.nn in VIM?

Tags: regex, vim

In Vim, I have opened a file with basically the following structure:

```
3677137  00:01:47.04
666239   00:12:57.86
4346     00:00:01.77
418  00:00:00.82
6564     00:00:01.34
1800     00:00:23.93
29208    00:14:23.32
```

That is: a number, followed by a tab (could also whitespace, I don't believe it matters) followed by an expression that indicates some amont of elapsed time in `HH:MM:SS.cs` format. (cs standing for centoseconds).

Now, I'd like to replace leading zeroes and colons and have found the following regexp to do exactly this:

```
:%s/\s\@<=[0:]\+//
```

resulting in

```
3677137  1:47.04
666239   12:57.86
4346     1.77
418  .82
6564     1.34
1800     23.93
29208    14:23.32
```

This is not bad and I could probably live with that. However, if there were an easy regex to have at least one figure in front of the `.` I'd probably be even more happy. That is, if the fourth line read

```
418  0.82
```

instead of

```
418  .82
```

So, is there a regexp that does that?

Comment: I would suggest: %s/\s\@<=[0:]\+\.\@!//

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest:

```
%s/\s\zs[0:]*\ze\d//
```

I tried it on your example and it seems to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Not the most elegant, but

```
:%s/\s00:0\?0\?:\?0\?//g
```